# Wordpress VM Instance not working correctly

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Everyday I need to restart the server, because the ip is not reachable and it stops generating logs. I don't know why because the server is on, but it seems like the wordpress instance shutsdown. don't know ... any clues?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question?

Comment: WordPress does not "run" in the same sense as a program. WordPress is a series of PHP scripts that are executed when an HTTP request arrives at the Apache server. Edit your question and clarify what you mean by "instance shutsdown". Find your Apache and PHP log files and review them for warnings and errors.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main reason this could be happening is due lack of disk space, you can check this going to:

1.- Navigation Menu ---> Compute engine ---> VM instances, Select your VM Instance 
2.- IN "VM instance details" click in Monitoring tab.

There you will se some graphics, take a look to Disk I/O (bytes) and Disk I/O (operations), if the graphics are very high could mean that you are getting out of disk space or reaching throughput/IOPS limits.

How do you fix this, [adding or resizing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/regional-persistent-disk) your disk should do the work.